# SBT: how to reuse code with parameters in multiple tasks?

Tags: scala, build, sbt

Sorry to say that SBT doesn't get much simpler with years...

I have a project using `sbt.version=0.13.5` and I defined a number of custom tasks in `Build.scala`.

I have a task which makes some repackaging of my artifacts, it is written using `:=` notation, as:

```
val myPackage = taskKey[File]("Package distributive")
val myPackageTask = myPackage := {
   // uses .value and streams
   // returns File of repackaged artifact
}
```

It works fine. However, I want to reuse that code calling it as a method/whatever with parameters as:

```
def myPackageCode(param: String): File = {
  // the same code using .value and streams only using the `param`
  // returns File as above
}

val packageNo1 = taskKey[File]("Package distributive option 1")
val packageNo1Task = packageNo1 := { myPackageCode("1") }

val packageNo2 = taskKey[File]("Package distributive option 2")
val packageNo2Task = packageNo2 := { myPackageCode("2") }
```

This fails to compile with: `value` can only be called on a task within a task definition macro, such as :=, +=, ++=, or Def.task.

How to make it work: reuse task code with parameters?

Comment: Any reason why you're still on 0.13? 1.0 has been out for three years at this point.

Comment: The reason is obvious, i have loads of projects and there is not enough time to keep each one up-to-date with versions of everything.

Comment: This just works with up-to-date versions of sbt. Perhaps you should take the time to update after all…

Comment: @MatthiasBerndt Sure it is an option, but there is a good saying "if it ain't broke, don't fix it"

Comment: But it did break, and you spent some significant time fixing it.

Comment: @MatthiasBerndt significantly less than if I would have debugged all possible issues with that non-trivial build code. And what's important - it distracts from primary goals.

Answer (score 2):

After trial and research I made it work as the following:

```
// wrapped the original code in Def.taskDyn { Def.task { ... }}
def myPackageCode(param: String) = Def.taskDyn { Def.task {
  // the same code using .value and streams only using the `param`
  // returns File as above
}}

val packageNo1 = taskKey[File]("Package distributive option 1")
// changed := to <<= in "assignment" to key
val packageNo1Task = packageNo1 <<= myPackageCode("1")
```

"Simple", as always with simple build tool :)

Comment: _Thank you!_ I've been trying to fix this for hours. The "simple" in SBT must be sarcastic.